# Alterar cor do Icone da Aba

Tags: android

Olá

Estou estou usando a classe [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) normalmente.

Mas gostaria que mudasse a cor ao selecionar o item ou o fragment

As configurações do slidingTabLayout que estou fazendo são essas no `onCreate`:

> **MainActivity.class**

```
slidingTabLayout.setCustomTabView( R.layout.tab_view, R.id.text_item_tab );
slidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly( true );
slidingTabLayout.setSelectedIndicatorColors(ContextCompat.getColor( this, R.color.colorTabIndicator ));
slidingTabLayout.setViewPager( viewPager );
```

> **SlidingTabLayout.class**

Dentro do método `populateTabStrip` adicionei algumas linhas e nada:

```
private void populateTabStrip() {
   /* resto do código */

  int color = ContextCompat.getColor( tabView.getContext(), R.color.colorTabIndicator );
  tabTitleView.setTextColor( color );

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você vai ter que criar uma lista com os 2 tipos de icones, list_normalicons, e list_selectedicons, ao ocorrer a transição, o seu imageview terá que alterar o icone

Comment: Resolvi utilizando um mais fácil. O TabLayout.

Comment: É uma boa opção =)